# postgresql regular expression and substring

Tags: regex, postgresql, substring

I have a regular expression `http\:\/\/domainname\.com\/\S{4}` which should catch urls like this: `http://domainname.com/key4` in a longer text.

I want to get only the key and match it with a table field in my postgres database.

after trying some stuff I came to this query (for grabbing keys):

```
SELECT substring(infos FROM '[http\:\/\/domainname\.com\/\S{4}]{7}' ) AS key FROM actions
```

as a result i get the `/domainname.com` for each row ... well, no keys as you can see.

what am I doing wrong?

can anyone tell me what the `{7}` stands for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{7}` stands for 7 times the previous pattern. So in this case, the **different characters** between `[` and `]`. i.e. `[abc]{3}` matches `aaa` `cba` or any other combination.

I'm fairly certain that this is not what you want. You are probably looking for something like this instead:

```
SELECT substring('http://domainname.com/key4' from 'http://domainname\\.com/\\S{4}')
FROM actions
```

Comment: @helle: can you give an example of how `infos` looks like? Cause it should work with the given expression (works with all testdata I've given it)

Comment: infos contains a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for in this specific case

```
select substring(substring('long text [http://domainname.com/key4] more text',E'http\:\/\/domainname\.com\/\\S{4}'),E'\\S{4}$');
```

which will extract the key part if it is four characters long. If you might also be looking for something like key456 then a more generic match such as

```
select substring(substring('long text [http://domainname.com/key467] more text',E'http\:\/\/domainname\.com\/key\\d+'),E'key\\d+$');
```

may be more appropriate